# How do I strip CDATA tag from RSS (XML) feed with RegEx?

Tags: javascript, html, regex, xml, rss

I'd like add my RSS feed to my website. I'm using a script that converts XML to HTML and injects into into the DOM. However, I'd like to include the title but it's wrapped in `<![CDATA[My Title]]>` tags. I've seen similar answers on how to strip these tags using RegEX. However, merging this solution with my script doesn't seem to work correctly.

I started by using a function as described here: [Clean away CDATA from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23634491/clean-away-cdata-from-string) however this didn't work either. Console logs an error of `Cannot read property '1' of null` as I guess it's looking for an array.

When I've added the RegEx into the loop that creates the HTML from the data and log the result I get `null`.

Any ideas?

Example JavaScript:

```
const app = document.querySelector(".article-list");
const PROXY_URL = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
const RSS_URL =
  "https://feedbin.com/starred/6d263eeb54a21502ba818684b4e96cac.xml";
fetch(PROXY_URL + RSS_URL)
  .then((response) => response.text())
  .then((str) => new window.DOMParser().parseFromString(str, "text/xml"))
  .then((data) => {
    const items = data.querySelectorAll("item");
    let html = ``;
    items.forEach((el) => {
      var url = new URL(el.querySelector("link").innerHTML);
      var title = el.querySelector("title").innerHTML;
      console.log(title);
      var pattern = new RegExp(/\<!\[CDATA\[.*?\/>(.*?)\]\]\>/);
      var res = pattern.exec(title)[1];
      console.log(res);
      html += `
        <li>
          <a class="card-list" href="${
            el.querySelector(" link").innerHTML
          }" targett="_blank" rel="noopener">
            <strong class="card-list__title">
              ${res}
            </strong>
            <div class="card-list__text">${url.hostname.replace(
              "www",
              ""
            )}</div>
          </a>
        </li>
      `;
    });
  app.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", html);
});
```

Link to an example CodePen: https://codepen.io/abbasarezoo/pen/156aafd2c915410fa11a42ac1ff2b8d0?editors=1011

Thanks in advance for any help.